# Simplest way to store this to do list data even after browser closed?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a web-based TO-DO list exactly like the one on the  [W3schools link below](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_todo), however when I close the browser all the inputs and edit disappear and it reverts back to the original.  Is it possible to easily store the values (if not I will quickly delete this Q)?  What code can I add to make it save the data (perhaps localstorage?) each time or would I have to set up a php/mySql?  No authentication required, whatever is the most straightforward way to do it.

The exact code is below.  I prefer to host locally for simplicty but if necessary web based hosting server is also fine with me.

[To Do List Example from W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_todo)

Comment: You can use localStorage or a server-side database, depending on what you want.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: This is arguably the simplest one - https://github.com/typicode/json-server

Comment: Maybe store it in cookies with infinite lifetime? should be pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript LocalStorage to save data on browser close, only if it is being loaded on a domain that is accessed via HTTP.

Though, you can use a server-side database, such as mySQL to store data.